# Error Refencing To a TableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, runtime-error, tableview

I am getting an error : `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` when I test my code on my device.

I am implementing some code to a TableViewController whereby certain TableView Cells are highlighted on touch/press.

I have isolated the problem to 'row 6' which is the last row of my TableView. When I comment out the code for this row, the code runs perfect.

I have set the number of rows programatically (and in StoryBoard) to 7.

I just don't see why the error occurs. Obviously it is unable to unwrap the last cell, but I don;t understand why.

Here is my code:

Note : Rows 0 and 1 (the first two rows) are not 'clickable' and thus they are not referenced in my code.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 7
}

//Make TableView Cells Highlight On Touch Respectively.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0))
    cell!.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 170/255, green: 139/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)


    let cell1  = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 3, inSection: 0))
    cell1!.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 138/255, green: 231/255, blue: 36/255, alpha: 1.0)

    let cell3  = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 0))
    cell3!.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 135/255, green: 190/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)

    let cell4  = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 5, inSection: 0))
    cell4!.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 250/255, green: 236/255, blue: 67/255, alpha: 1.0)

    let cell5  = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 6, inSection: 0))
    cell5!.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 182/255, green: 181/255, blue: 182/255, alpha: 1.0)


}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0))
    cell!.contentView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()

    let cell1  = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 3, inSection: 0))
    cell1!.contentView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()


    let cell3  = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 0))
    cell3!.contentView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()

    let cell4  = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 5, inSection: 0))
    cell4!.contentView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()

    let cell5  = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 6, inSection: 0))
    cell5!.contentView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()

}
```

Thank you for your time in advance :-)

Comment: Are all of the cells visible at all times?

Comment: Part of the last cell is hidden in the StoryBoard (nav bar at top issue). But it still should be 'visible' when I run the project. The answer below did solve my problem - @Andrew McKinley - credit to him :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid forced unwrapping at nearly all costs!

```
if let cell5  = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 6, inSection: 0)){
    cell5.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 182/255, green: 181/255, blue: 182/255, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Comment: Agreed with he forced unwrapping advice. Has caused me many an issue! Will follow your advice from now on. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple docs for cellForRowAtIndexPath

**Return Value
An object representing a cell of the table, or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.**

You make instance variables in the method to reference the cells and force unwrap them in the next line. The last cell you are trying to force unwrap is probably not visible and the method is returning nil because the cell doesn't exist / the cell for that row has not been dequeued.

You likely want want to either guard against nil cells with if let statements if you really want all the cells to change color, or a switch statement if you only intend to change the color of one cell.

Comment: Duly noted Sir, with gratitude.